# Whether this series converge or not.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

\begin{equation}
a_n = \frac{1}{n(\log n)^p(\log \log n)^q}, \text{where } p,q \ge 0.
\end{equation}
Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$ converge? Should I use Bertrand's method?

Comment: The series should start at $n=3.$ Otherwise you have $\ln( \ln 2)<0$ and you have trouble with the $q$th power.

Comment: My mistake, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Cauchy's Condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) the the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log(n))^p(\log(\log(n)))^q}$ converges or diverges if and only if the condensed series, given by

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{2^n}{(2^n)\,(\log(2^n))^p(\log(\log(2^n))^q}=\frac{1}{\log^p(2)}\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{n^p(\log(n\log(2))^q} \tag 1$$

converges or diverges.

Now, using [Bertrand's Methodology](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html), we see that the series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ diverges for $p<1$, converges for $p>1$, and for $p=1$ the series converges for $q>1$ and diverges otherwise.

---

Alternatively, by enforcing the substitution $x=e^t$, we can see that

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x(\log(x))^p(\log(\log(x)))^q}\,dx=\int_{\log(2)}^\infty \frac{1}{t^p\log^q(t)}\,dt$$

which converges for $p>1$, diverges for $p<1$, and for $p=1$, converges for $q>1$ and diverges otherwise, which agrees with the previous result.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean:

*When does $\sum a_n$ converges regarding $p$ and $q$?*

**Hint**

Use a comparaison to an integral to evaluate the convergence.

(This is indeed similar to Bertrand's method)

Comment: Can you say a little more?

Comment: @S.Bryant Look closely at the proof for Bertrand's method, and try to adapt it in your case :)